# How to edit STL model files

Tags: 3d-models, stl

The slicer included with my printers (ChituBox) has no STL editing capabilities. How to edit STL models?

Comment: Have you tried Meshmixer?

Comment: "Favorite" is opinion based. I do retouch STLs with Blender, Meshmixer and Fusion360 as I see fit

Comment: tinkercad is a free online solution i've used to touch up thingiverse files.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on your use case.

As Bobt already commented, Meshmixer is a common tool for editing STLs.
But also a lot of CAD-Tools should be able to import STLs.
Then there is also of course Blender.

As you didn't specify what you want to use it for, I would guess you just want to do some quick fixes to the mesh.
The tool I use is Meshmixer. It's pretty powerful, but I personally never really used a lot of it's capabilities.

Comment: Blender is more powerful (just look at some of the [tag:blender] questions), but not easy to use.